# Values Clustering

Tags: java, hashmap

In a text file the data is distributed like shown below, I am considering this as table for ease.

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 
    A          B      1       2 
    A          B      1       5
    A          C      1       3 
    B          C      2       3
    C          A      3       4
    A          B      4       5
```

I need to cluster the the same values if column1 and column2 is same, like `A->B` is repeated 3 times combine like this.

```
 A          B      1       2 
 A          B      1       5
 A          B      4       5
```

Comment: Where you are storing your `column3` ?

Comment: Cool but, do you have a question?

Comment: @JBNizet the question how to cluster these similar ones.

Comment: @MandarPandit I am missing column3

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

1. Define a class Record containing the 4 fields
2. Define a class RecordKey containing the identification of a row, i.e. the two first column values. Make sure equals and hashCode are properly defined.
3. Create a `Map<RecordKey, List<Record>>`.
4. Read the records line by line. If there is already a list in the map for the current record key, then add the current record to this list. Otherwise, create a new list, add the record to it, and put this list in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Providing memory is not an issue then simply loading them into a `List` and then sorting them with those two columns as a compound key will cause them to cluster.   I would suggest creating a simple class to store each record, then using `list.sort(new Comparator<MyRecord>(){...});`

The compare method will be fairly straightforward if you can be sure you have no `null`s in your keys:

```
        @Override
        public int compare(MyRecord a, MyRecord b) {
            int n = a.getFirst().compareTo(b.getFirst());
            if (n == 0)
                return a.getSecond().compareTo(b.getSecond());
            return n;
        }
```

If you can have nulls then you'll need to be a bit more careful and check for them

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type of Map structure.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Record>>> parentMap
```

Record is a pojo in which you can store entire record.

```
public class Record {
    private String column1;
    private String column2;
    private Integer column3;
    private Integer column4;

    //getter setter
}
```

And in map you can put like this.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Record>>> parentMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,List<Record>>>();
Map<String, List<Record>> innerMap;
List<Record> innerList;
Record r;
for (Record loop) {
    innerMap = parentMap.get(column1);

    if (innerMap == null || innerMap.size() == 0) {
        innerMap = new HashMap<String, List<Record>>();
        parentMap.put(column1, innerMap);
    }
    innerList = innerMap.get(column2);
    if (innerList == null || innerList.size() == 0) {
        innerList = new ArrayList<Record>();
        innerMap.put(column2, innerList);
    }
    r = new Record();
    //set values in r

    innerList.add(r);
}
```

Comment: Record is a `poja` what this means ?

Comment: Sorry, its spelling mistake. It is pojo (Plain Old Java Object)